# Cannot convert rvalue std::array to std::span

Tags: c++, stl, std, c++20

Consider the following code.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <span>

std::array<int, 2> Foo()
{
    return {1, 2};
}

int main()
{    
    std::array a = {3, 4};
    std::span s1 = a;
    
    // std::span s2 = Foo(); // Nope
    // std::span s3 = std::move(a); // Nope
    // std::span s4 = std::array<int, 2>{5, 6}; // Nope

    // MSVC 19.29: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::array<int,2>' to 'std::span<int,18446744073709551615>'
    // GCC 12.0.0: conversion from 'std::array<int, 2>' to non-scalar type 'std::span<int, 18446744073709551615>' requested
    // clang 13.0.0: actually compiles!
}
```

It seems like `std::array` can be converted to an `std::span` when it's an rvalue only on clang.

I'm not sure if this is the root of the issue but here's MSVC's implementation of `std::array`-related constructors of `std::span`.

```cpp
    template <class _OtherTy, size_t _Size>
        requires (_Extent == dynamic_extent || _Extent == _Size)
              && is_convertible_v<_OtherTy (*)[], element_type (*)[]>
    constexpr span(array<_OtherTy, _Size>& _Arr) noexcept : _Mybase(_Arr.data(), _Size) {}

    template <class _OtherTy, size_t _Size>
        requires (_Extent == dynamic_extent || _Extent == _Size)
              && is_convertible_v<const _OtherTy (*)[], element_type (*)[]>
    constexpr span(const array<_OtherTy, _Size>& _Arr) noexcept : _Mybase(_Arr.data(), _Size) {}
```

At first glance I don't see anything wrong with it. An rvalue should bind to a const lvalue reference.

My question is: should this code compile (and it's an issue with the former compilers) or not (and it's an issue with the latter compiler)?

Comment: It's a simplified case of a bigger issue that I don't present here for clarity hence it might look like a bad use case, I understand that.

Comment: Sometimes the simplified version changes the nature of the question too much and you run the risk of getting unusable answers.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks but in this case it doesn't since I'm only interested in whether the code should compile or not.

Comment: It not compiling is a **good** thing. If this was allowed the `std::span` would point to memory that has been cleaned up. Would you think this code is valid: `std::string_view sv{ std::string{ "Hello there" } }`?. An `std::span` like `std::string_view` does not take ownership of the object.

Comment: @康桓瑋, ah, ok. clang 12 doesn't accept it either.  https://godbolt.org/z/r3sz6nzE1. clang 12 accepts `span<int const, 2> s2 = Foo();` though (which get you into more trouble). (In any case, I must say :`span` what a horrible, semantics, name and design!)

Comment: @alfC. You need to turn on the `-stdlib=libc++` flag. https://godbolt.org/z/b3YnEvx3j

Comment: Does the above code compile?

Comment: Valid (I meant without lifetime issue) example usage would be `void print(std::span<const int>)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR. This is just because libc++ has not yet implemented
[P1394](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21//docs/papers/2019/p1394r4.pdf).

---

The problem is that in [libstd++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/span#L410) and [MSVC-STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/9a9820df1a1d3fa84100e3169ff37fdd4fa41759/stl/inc/span#L663), `std::span` has the following CTAD:

```
template<typename _Range>
    span(_Range &&)
      -> span<remove_reference_t<ranges::range_reference_t<_Range&>>>;
```

When we call `std::span{std::array{0}}`, the type of `span` will be deduced to `span<int>`, and we will call `span<int>::span(const array<int, 1>&)`, but this constructor has the [following constraints](http://eel.is/c++draft/views.span#span.cons-11):

> *Constraints*: Let `U` be `remove_­pointer_­t<decltype(data(arr))>`.
>
> - `extent == dynamic_­extent || N == extent` is `true`, and
> - `is_­convertible_­v<U(*)[], element_­type(*)[]>` is `true`.

Since the return type of `arr.data()` is `const int*` and `element_type` is `int`, the value of `is_convertible_v<const int(*)[], int(*)[]>` is false, so the constraint is not satisfied.

---

This CTAD is not available in [libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/12b34e056cf19d9c2c2a7f180ba26991bba3f16c/libcxx/include/span#L559-L573), so `std::span{std::array{0}}` will use the following CTAD:

```
template<class _Tp, size_t _Sz>
    span(const array<_Tp, _Sz>&) -> span<const _Tp, _Sz>;
```

And call `span<const int, 1>::span(array<const int, 1>&)`, which is just... work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether r-value conversion of `std::array` to `std::span` should be a compilation error or not but such conversion is most likely a bug and usage of such a span will probably cause UB.

Basically, `span` is a viewer while `array` is a container. R-values are presumed to be temporaries, therefore, `span` initialized from a temporary container is likely to point towards destroyed piece of data and it's usage is undefined.

There are cases where it is a legitimate operation - like wrapping an array for a call. But generally, it is unsafe and dangerous. For the "array wrapping by span" you can always create a helper function if needed.